# Formatting string and inserting object into string

Tags: java, string-formatting

If I have a line of code like so:

```
String formattedString = String.format("... {}", objectToBeInserted);
```

I want the `objectToBeInserted` to be inserted into the string where the `{}` is. How would I go about doing so if I don't necessarily know the data type of `objectToBeInserted`?

Comment: `String::format` formats the string using a *[formatting string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)*. The documentation says you can use `%s` for objects. It will indeed invoke the object's `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you bring up %d at the end of your question, when it doesn't actually occur in the format string that you mentioned.

Anyway, the short answer is that you don't have to know the data type of objectToBeInserted. The `format()` method will simply invoke `toString()` on your object and whatever that returns, will be put at the place where the `{}` is.

The %d directive is for formatting decimal numbers, which is not the case in your example. (Even if `toString()` returns something like `"42"`, it will be treated as a string, not as a number.)

Comment: this doesn't work - using {} will just leave the "{}" in the string instead of replacing it

Comment: OK, seems that I didn't clarify things enough. So here's the longer answer: There are two "systems" of format placeholders - one is the %-notation, and the other is the {}-notation. `String.format()` uses the %-notation. The {} notation is used by the class `MessageFormat`. They are similar and you can use whichever you like. MessageFormat is used more for translating messages to other languages and has a simpler syntax. String.format() is used for actually **fomatting** stuff and has way more options. The correct directive in your case is `%s` since you want to insert a string, not a number.

Comment: @Mike I think it's better to included this in your post instead of posting it as a comment.